# parsing rss different tags extract image

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to extract the images from multiple sites rss.

First rss

```
<enclosure type="image/jpeg" length="321742" url="http://www.sitio.com.uy//uploads/2014/10/19/54441d68e01af.jpg"/>
```

Second rss

```
<g:image_link>http://img.sitio2.com/imagenes/314165_20150422201743_635653477836873822w.jpg</g:image_link>
```

Need extract url of image.

My code is with Beatifulsoup in python

```
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

    items = soup.find_all('item')

    for item in items:
        title = item.find('title').get_text().encode('utf-8')
        description = item.find('description').get_text().encode('utf-8')
        category = item.find('category').get_text().encode('utf-8')
        image = item.find('enclosure')

        print(image)
```

Comment: Not functionally for g:image_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for multiple tags using a tag list.

```
item.find(['enclosure', 'g:image_link'])
```

This will return the first tag it finds. If there are multiple tags use `find_all`.

```
item.find_all(['enclosure', 'g:image_link'])
```

Comment: how can I extract just url and type image?